# Программа, отправляющая список команд на сервер и постоянно считывающая сообщения от сервера

Tags: java, android, сокет, tcp

Приложение отправляет сообщения на сервер, реализовано в отдельном потоке mThr, но мне надо еще постоянно, с самого запуска приложения, считывать информацию с сервера, который ее отправляет (каждые 2 сек), пытался эту операцию в отдельный поток mThr2 поместить, но видимо это делается не так. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    public static String SERVERIP;
    public static int SERVERPORT;
    String message;
    public String serverMessage;
    public int i = 0;
    public Socket client = null;
    public DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    public DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
private DataAdapter mAdapter;
public ArrayList<String> move = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> clientList = new ArrayList<String>();
int[][] pm = {
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Button clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button clientC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final EditText ips = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipstr);
    final EditText thread = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText ports = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.portstr);
    final TextView serverKuka = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mThr2.start();
    clientC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GraphOfActions g = new GraphOfActions();
            move = g.FinalCommandList(clientList);
        }
    });
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            move.clear();
            clientList.clear();
            i = 0;
        }
    });

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SERVERIP = ips.getText().toString();
            SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(ports.getText().toString());
            move.add("LUA_Base(0,0,0.0)^^^");
            move.add("end");
            String result = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < move.size(); j++) {
                result += move.get(j) + " ";
                //try {
                   // mThr.start();
                //    message = move.get(j);
                    //Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(thread.getText().toString()) * 1000);
               // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //}
            }
            mThr.start();
            message = result;
            mThr.interrupt();
        }
    });
    final GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    g.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    g.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i++;
            clientList.add(mAdapter.getItem(position));
        }
    });
}

Thread mThr2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            client = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            serverMessage = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
});

Thread mThr = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            //dataOutputStream.writeBytes(message);
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(message);
            serverMessage = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
});

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                           long id) {
    //mSelectText.setText("Выбранный элемент: " + mAdapter.getItem(position));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    //mSelectText.setText("Выбранный элемент: ничего");
}
}
```